# Using a Django model from a mercurial python hook

Tags: python, django, django-models, mercurial, mercurial-hook

I'm trying to queue up some build requests in a DB during a changegroup hook. The DB table is managed by a Django app. So, in the hook, I want to use the Django model to submit the build request. However, I'm unable to get my settings right to import the model successfully.

Based on this (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/) info, all I need to do is add my django site to the sys path, and set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. The django site lives in /opt/mysite, so - trying this from the python console:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> sys.path.append('/opt')
>>> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
>>> from mysite.myapp.models import Build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/mysite/myapp/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/db/__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/db/utils.py", line 33, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.db import utils
ImportError: cannot import name utils
>>>
```

**Second Attempt:**

Based on this (http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/) I can use setup_environ(), when I try this in the python shell, it works:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/opt')
>>> from django.core.management import setup_environ
>>> from mysite import settings
>>> setup_environ(settings)
'/opt/mysite'
>>> from mysite.myapp.models import Build
>>> Build.objects.all()
[<Build: #1 F nkj sdfsdfsdfs43qg test_branch>, <Build: #2 F nkj sdfsdfsdfs43qg test_branch>, <Build: #13 Q   >, <Build: #14 Q   nkj_bug243>, <Build: #11 F nkj 444hwe45hedrrt nkj_bug272>, <Build: #12 F nkj sdfsdfsdfs43qg test_branch>]
```

However, when I try this in my Mercurial hook, I get blasted with errors the minute I try to import my Build model:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
path = '/opt'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

from django.core.management import setup_environ
from mysite import settings
setup_environ(settings)

from mysite.myapp.models import Build
import datetime

... do stuff ...
```

When it gets to the 'from mysite.myapp.models import Build' line I get the following error output:

```
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
**  http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) [GCC 4.6.1]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.9.1)
** Extensions loaded:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hg", line 38, in <module>
    mercurial.dispatch.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 27, in run
    sys.exit(dispatch(request(sys.argv[1:])))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 64, in dispatch
    return _runcatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 87, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 679, in _dispatch
    cmdpats, cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 454, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 733, in _runcommand
    return checkargs()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 687, in checkargs
return cmdfunc()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 676, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 385, in check
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 3884, in push
    newbranch=opts.get('new_branch'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 1428, in push
lock=lock)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 1849, in addchangegroup
source=srctype, url=url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 224, in hook
    return hook.hook(self.ui, self, name, throw, **args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/hook.py", line 160, in hook
    mod = extensions.loadpath(path, 'hghook.%s' % hname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/extensions.py", line 45, in loadpath
    return imp.load_source(module_name, path)
  File "/opt/unapse/belvedere/mercurial_hook.py", line 14, in <module>
    from unapse.belvedere.models import Build
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 109, in _demandimport
    mod = _origimport(name, globals, locals)
  File "/opt/unapse/belvedere/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 109, in _demandimport
    mod = _origimport(name, globals, locals)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/db/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/conf/__init__.py", line 139, in __init__
    logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 776, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 575, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'mail_admins': __import__() argument 1 must be string, not DictConfigurator
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing this problem?

Comment: Check out this article about running standalone Django scripts... http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/

Comment: That's for the tip, I read the article and tried to implement one of the methods there. It worked for me in the python console, but when I tried the same thing in my mercurial hook, it failed. I've updated my post with the output from that attempt.

Answer (score 1):

The DictConfigurator error is a bug in python, hopefully fixed in the next 2.7 release (http://bugs.python.org/issue12718), something (probably mercurial) is overriding **import** and python's logging code fails in that case.

Until then here is what I did to fix it. Copy dictconfig.py from django/utils to somewhere in your python system path (I put it alongside my hook). Change the line

```
importer = __import__
```

to:

```
def importer(self, *args):
    return __import(*args)__
```

And then in settings.py for your django project add to the end:

```
LOGGING_CONFIG = 'website.dictconfig.dictConfig'
```

Update website.dictconfig to whatever path you put the dictconfig file into so python can find it.

**UPDATE**: I think there is an even easier way. Add this to the top of your hook script, before importing anything else:

```
from mercurial import demandimport;
demandimport.disable()
```

This makes Mercurial revert the **import** override and seems to solve the problem cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running with your environment in a virtualenv dir you'll need to add that to the site packages and I'd also suggest that you put the django dir at the front of `sys.path` instead of the end.

Here's the code we use to integrate our Django app into other python apps.

```
import os
import sys

# point this at the virtualenv dir that your django deployment runs out of
# you are using virtualenv. right?
DJANGO_ENV = '/home/core/python-envs/production'

# where your code lives (ie where settings.py is)
DJANGO_DIR = '/home/core/code/production'

# add our site packages
import site
site_packages = os.path.join(DJANGO_ENV, 'lib', 'python%s' % sys.version[:3], 'site-packages')
site.addsitedir(site_packages)

# put the main Django directory on first
sys.path.insert(0, DJANGO_DIR)

# setup the Django environment pointing to our settings
import settings
import django.core.management
django.core.management.setup_environ(settings)

# finally, import our objects
from yourapp.models import YourModel
```

One last thing to note is that when we import our code into some applications we've run into scoping issues and imports clashing. To get around it we wrap the work we want to do in a function so that it gets its own scope.

For example, instead of:

```
from yourapp.models import YourModel
objs = YourModel.objects.filter(something=True)
...
```

Do something like:

```
def do_work():
    from yourapp.models import YourModel
    objs = YourModel.objects.filter(something=True)
    ...
do_work()
```